# Have movable image in PyQt/PySide that wraps one edge to the other edge when moved (similar an interactive map)

Tags: pyqt, pyside, qimage, qpixmap

I have a CSV colormap image and want it to be able to move horizontally and (similar to an interactive world map like google maps) have one side wrap back to the other side when moved, like so:

[original CSV colormap]
[image]

[wrapped CSV map]
[image]

In other words, move the left edge back to the right edge when the left edge is moved out of frame (and of course, the same thing but in opposite directions for the right edge).

Currently, I just I have the image displayed in a pixmap on a label. I have not yet figured out how to move the image, let alone have it wrap around like I want.

Comment: See this partially related question: [Is there any way to display a 360-degree image in PyQt5 Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57260345). Fundamentally speaking, you need to scroll the image, but since you want to do it "infinitely" you cannot use a scroll area, nor a QLabel: painting has to be done on your own.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.